# Jquery Scrollable can't stop autoplay when nav is clicked

Tags: jquery, onclick, scrollable, nav

I'm using jquery UI tools scrollable with a nav. I want it so that it autoplays automatically, which is fine, but the timing goes all funky whenever I interact with the nav.

I want it to stop when I click on any of the nav links. I can't seem to get scrolling to stop!

Here's the code that kicks it off:

HTML:

```
    <div id="flowpanes"> 
        <div class="items">
            <div>
                <h1>Content 1</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Content 2</h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Content 3</h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Content 4</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul id="flowtabs" class="navi">
        <li><a href="#one" class="current"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#two"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#three"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#four"></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Jquery that activates it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#flowpanes").scrollable({ circular: true, mousewheel: true }).autoscroll({autoplay: true,interval: 5000,steps: 1}).navigator({
        navi: ".navi",
        naviItem: 'a',
        activeClass: 'current',
        history: false,
    })
});
```

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
$(".navi a").click (function(){
    api.stop()
});
```

Then I tried adding js to the actual buttons,  but I don't think I'm specifying it correctly - does something like the below code need something else to pin point the scrollable area - the scrolling content is in a spearate div above ul.navi:

```
 <ul id="flowtabs" class="navi">
   <li><a href="#one" class="current" onclick="api.stop()"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#two" onclick="api.stop()"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#three" onclick="api.stop()"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#four" onclick="api.stop()"></a></li>
 </ul>
```

I also tried adding clickable: false to the navigator section under history: false, but that didn't work either.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is 'api'? Where is it defined?

Comment: Which `.scrollable` are you using? There are many of them.

Comment: @Ariel - I'm using the autoscroll one from [this page]http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/plugins/index.html#autoscroll

Comment: @JoeyvanOmmen further down on the link in my comment to Ariel, is an example of using api.stop() - The very bottom has the scenario I currently have. If you click on the navigator buttons randomly, when you stop and move your mouse away, the interval timings are all over the place. This is why I want to stop autoplay when you click on any of the nav links - does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look the sourcecode of the jquery ui scroller example at [jQuery Scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/autoscroll.html) they use this instruction for assigning the api object to the current window:

```
// provide scrollable API for the action buttons
window.api = root.data("scrollable");
```

have you tried it?

Comment: I haven't! I think that might be my solution - I'll try it now and hopefully give a nice big tick mark beside your answer :)

Comment: thank you so much. I was ready to throw my computer at the window.

Comment: For others who might have the same problem, I essentially edited the beginning of my jquery to be: var root = $("#flowpanes").scrollable .... and added the line: window.api = root.data("scrollable");

Comment: I'm happy for you, happy coding!