# Re-Starting Jquery Tools Scrollable after Stopping - Using API

Tags: api, jquery-tools, scrollable

I'm using the Jquery Tools Scrollable plugin [like this example](http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/plugins-chain.htm), and I would like to have custom buttons that would make it Start and Stop. I can get it to stop autoscrolling, but I can't get it to resume autoscrolling from where I stopped it.

Here's how I initialize it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// heeeeeeeeeeere we go.
var root = $("#chained").scrollable({circular: true, mousewheel: true, 
easing:'easeInOutQuint', speed: 1200}).navigator().autoscroll({
interval: 3000
});

// provide scrollable API for the action buttons
window.api = root.data("scrollable");

});
```

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896764/jquery-scrollable-cant-stop-autoplay-when-nav-is-clicked), I can make it "Stop." I also know that I can also make it "Begin" - go to the first slide - by using these:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick="api.begin();">Start</a>
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick="api.stop();">Stop</a>
```

Although it does go to the first pane/slide, it not longer autoscrolls. Is there a way to get it to resume autoscrolling in the location where I "Stopped" it? Also, is the `window.api=root.data("scrollable");` approach deprecated? Should I approach that differently?

TIA for any suggestions.